# Python - append list to other list?

Tags: python, list

Leetcode 113 - Path Sum II

Given the root of a binary tree and an integer targetSum, return all root-to-leaf paths where each path's sum equals targetSum.

```
# Definition for a binary tree node.
# class TreeNode:
#     def __init__(self, val=0, left=None, right=None):
#         self.val = val
#         self.left = left
#         self.right = right

class Solution:
    def pathSum(self, root: TreeNode, targetSum: int) -> List[List[int]]:
        if not root: return []
        
        res = []
        
        def dfs(node, total = 0, path = []):
            if not node: return 
            
            path.append(node.val)
            total += node.val
            if not node.left and not node.right and total == targetSum:
                res.append(list(path))
            else:
                dfs(node.left, total, path)
                dfs(node.right, total, path)
            total -= path.pop()
        
        dfs(root)
        return res
```

Why we have to use `res.append(list(path))` rather than use `res.append(path)`?

If we only append `path` into res, it would only append empty list into `res`.

Comment: Please provide the expected [MRE - Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).
Show where the intermediate results deviate from the ones you expect.  We should be able to paste a single block of your code into file, run it, and reproduce your problem.  This also lets us test any suggestions in your context.
Most of all, please explain *exactly* what you don't understand from the output you get when you trace this code. Include that trace in your MRE.

Comment: In short, what is the output difference between the two statements in each call?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I'm not sure how to post the exactly problem. But I can post the link of this problem on the Leetcode. https://leetcode.com/problems/path-sum-ii/.

Comment: Input: [5,4,8,11,null,13,4,7,2,null,null,5,1] 22; Correct output: [[5,4,11,2], [5,8,4,5]]; My output if I didn't add `list(path)`: [[], []]

Answer (score -1):

This is a subtle Python issue.  When you use a default parameter like that (in the `def dfs` line), it captures that default object at definition time.  So, every time that function runs, `path` is set to the SAME empty list.  If you change that list, everyone with a reference to it sees the change.  I believe they use list(path) to make a copy of that list, rather than store a link to the common list.

Comment: The default only applies if the `path` argument isn't provided. But it always is, except for the single root call.

Comment: Thanks! Learn a new basic concept from this question.